# Zener diode in parallel with both the input terminals and the output terminals

Tags: diodes, schematics, zener, fuses, reverse-polarity

> There is a zener diode in parallel with both the input terminals and the output terminals. Combined with the fuse these should help in reverse polarity situations (it should blow the fuse before damaging onboard components).

How would that look in a schematic?

It's from the [QuinLED-Dig-Uno Hardware guide](https://quinled.info/2018/10/12/quinled-dig-uno-hardware-guide/). I want to understand it.

This is my try but I´m not sure if it works:

[Valid XHTML](https://n8970q34vnvidunh897qfc5wenh87v.tk/s/42fAijomdHHKRs5/preview).

Comment: Marlon: I don't know what others think of your question, but to me it has all the earmarks of a homework question (with no attempt at a solution). I am therefore reluctant to answer it.  I would suggest you give us a diagram what you **think** it should look like, then we are more free to comment. You can use the 'edit' button and there is a free schematic editor available.

Comment: It is not. Its from this website: https://quinled.info/2018/10/12/quinled-dig-uno-hardware-guide/ I want to understand it. ![Valid XHTML](https://n8970q34vnvidunh897qfc5wenh87v.tk/s/42fAijomdHHKRs5/preview).

Answer (score 1):

First a correction: they are diodes or schottky diodes, not zener diodes!

The idea is that if the voltage is connected the 'wrong' way, that the diode starts conducting in the forward direction and short-circuits the input. The the fuse blows and the circuit is safe.

Although nice on paper there is always the question: what blows first, the diode or the fuse? For this to work your fuse has to be small and light and the diode has to be heavy and robust. Also this does not work if power comes from U8. (But I thihnk that should not happen anyways. But what is D3 for then?Seems a bit redundant). I also have some doubts about SS12. There will be a voltage drop over the shottky? diode and your NodeMCU does not get the full 5V.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: There is nothing to fix. Two diodes in parallel is a bit much but not really wrong. The thing to check is the max. current of the diodes versus the fuse value. I have no idea why SS12 is in there but if is a good shottky you lose ~150-250mV, not fatal.

Comment: The SS12 ist there if the nodemcu gets power from the USB port no other components get powered from the NodeMCU